# embed pdf in html and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, pdf, mod-rewrite

I would like to capture accesses to pdf files and generate 
an html response with the pdf embeded in an object tag or a frame

I tried with `mod_rewrite` in my **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.pdf$ pdf.php [L]
```

and **pdf.php** something like

```
$uri=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
print("<center><object data='$uri' type=application/pdf width=728px height=90%>");
```

it captures the pdf access but displays an empty gray frame without the pdf
I suspect that the rewrite engine tries to apply the rule again to the 
embeded pdf file ?

Answer (score 0):

Why using deprecated `<center>`?

Use `'` for string values `<object data='{$uri}' type='application/pdf' style='width: 728px; height: 90%'>`

Comment: This is not an answer to my question

Anyway, for the quoted string I have learned since the 90's that quotes are not mandatory when there is no space in the string. this is quite convenient when mixing languages and quicker to write. even if <center> is deprecated I don't think tha it will disapear.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution first in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !escape=1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It does what I want: when I access first my.pdf it goes to index.php with

```
$uri=$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (endsWith($uri,".pdf")) {
    $out="<center><object data='$uri?escape=1' type=application/pdf width=728px height=90%>";
    print($out);
    return;
}
```

Then the query strind escape=1 makes the rule index.php skipped.

By the way, I can add header and footer (e.g. adsense) to any file.

The rules also applies to html files.